# How do I make np.multiply use more than one core?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, blas, numpy-ufunc

The title says it already. I am currently parallelizing my code and a major bottleneck is posed by element-wise multiplication of two three-dimensional `ndarrays`. My system monitor reveals that only one of the `40` available cores is used for that operation.

I know parallelization works, because the other `scipy.fft` and BLAS operations run in parallel.

So far, I have not really found any meaningful questions/issues on SO or GitHub. It is a bit bewildering that no one else has had this issue. Am I missing something?

I tried playing with BLAS environment variables and using `dgbmv` with flattened arrays to achieve the desired behaviour but I have not been successful, yet. A minimal code example would be (with much larger `k`, 3d arrays, and broadcasting involved in my case):

```py
import numpy as np
k = 1e6
x = np.random.rand(k)
y = np.random.rand(k)
z = np.multiply(x, y)
```

Comment: Numpy does not use multiple thread. Blas operation are parallel because of BLAS library themselves. Numpy just call them from a sequential code. AFAIK, there is no parallel BLAS functions for that. Thus, you need to do it yourself or to use another module since Numpy simply cannot. AFAIK Numexpr can do that. You can do it trivially and manually in Cython or Numba too.

Comment: if you have a compatible cpu, you can use [pnumpy](https://pypi.org/project/pnumpy/)

Comment: BLAS are often not perfect when it comes to parallelization of complex cases. OpenBLAS for example has such issues (the matrix needs to be not too small nor too huge and rather squared for good parallelisation and many functions LAPACK are not well parallelised yet because it is hard).

Comment: You should not expect the code to be 40x faster on a 40 cores. This computation is memory-bound. We optimised Numpy so to use core at their maximum capacity as much as possible (it is still not optimal in many case but it should be close on this function on x86-64 CPU). Memory bound codes are limited by the RAM so using more core does not help much. Still, on servers, 1 core can hardly saturate the RAM so few core are needed for optimal performance.

Comment: I personally advise not to use the Numpy model of programming for parallel code. It is not efficient due to function being memory bound. Numba/Cython code with plain loops avoiding temporary arrays/stores can be much more efficient since they are *cache friendly* (and CPU caches tend to scale with the number of cores).

Comment: Thank you for your fast answers. `pnumpy` gives me a speedup factor of around 1.6 so although I don't need to change the code, I prefer `numexpr`(see below). Thank you for the insights into NumPy, I might do a Numba implementation in the fututre. I did not expect the code to run 40x times faster but it seemed unecessarily slow.

Comment: There's also [jax](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which performs better than `numexpr` on my machine

Comment: Thanks! Without diving into `jax`, it is slightly faster than `numexpr` but only because it uses `float32`. I need double precision. In fact, `numexpr` is even faster than (out of the box) `jax` on my machine (no GPU) when using single precision.

Comment: the documentation for enabling double precision in jax is [here](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#double-64bit-precision)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to have a look at numexpr : https://pypi.org/project/numexpr/2.6.1/

This lib is supposed to use all your cores.

You can use it like this :

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

k = int(1e6)
x = np.random.rand(k)
y = np.random.rand(k)

z = ne.evaluate('x * y')
```

Comment: Thanks. With `numexpr` all cores are used. It works as expected for higher dimensional arrays with broadcasting as well. I get a speedup of factor 5-10 on my machine!